# Keras model_to_estimator doesn't log metrics on estimator.train, but logs on estimator.evaluate

Tags: tensorflow, logging, metrics, tensorflow-estimator, tf.keras

I tried the keras [model_to_estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/keras_model_to_estimator) to build an estimator, but found that it wasn't logging metrics during training, although it does during evaluation.

If that doesn't work out of the box, how can I use tf.summary.scalar or hooks in an estimator that consumes a tf.keras model?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]